# Delete player from MySQL database

Tags: java, mysql, bukkit

I have a command that kicks a player from a MySQL database, but it's not working when the player is offline; it won't delete them from the database.

Here's my code:

```
this.ms.connect();
PreparedStatement kick = this.ms.prepare("DELETE FROM `players` WHERE `nick` = ?");

try {
    kick.setString(1, args[0]);
} catch (SQLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

this.ms.execute(kick);
```

The error I get is:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: OfflinePlayer cannot be null
```

Comment: What's your entire code?

Comment: is `args[0]` set correctly? without the surrounding code this is v hard to understand.

Comment: You should use UUIDs instead of names.
``Bukkit.getOfflinePlayer(uuid)``

Answer (score 0):

This is very unclear but if `nick` is the player's username then do:

```
Bukkit.getOfflinePlayer(args[0]).getName()
```

Remember, `args[0]` should be the username but if it's the UUID then do:

```
Bukkit.getOfflinePlayer(UUID.fromString(args[0]))
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the players uuid, if you can not find the offline player by it‘s exact name. Also, make sure, that all your mySql requests are working on a new Async thread, not in the main server thread.